# How do I join on multiple columns in SQL Server and include columns in one table that aren't present in other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with a similar schema as Example Table 1 and Example Table 2. Both tables have columns that identify the data which are in both tables. Columns A and B are in both tables.

Table 1:

```
Col A   | Col B | Col C | Col D  
--------+-------+-------+------
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-1   | D-1  
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-2   | D-2  
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-3   | D-3  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-4   | D-4   
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-5   | D-5
```

Table 2:

```
Col A   | Col B | Col E  
--------+-------+------
Cat 1   | Bla a | E-1   
Cat 2   | Bla b | E-2   
Cat 2   | Bla b | E-3   
Cat 2   | Bla b | E-4
```

Desired Output Table:

```
Col A   | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E  
--------+-------+-------+-------+------
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-1   | D-1   | E-1   
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-2   | D-2   | NULL  
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-3   | D-3   | NULL  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-4   | D-4   | E-2    
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-5   | D-5   | E-3   
Cat 2   | Bla b | NULL  | NULL  | E-4
```

I need to combine, merge, update, loop or somehow find a method that results in a single table. In this single table I need the values in the columns that are unique to Example Table 1 to align with the common columns values as they did in the Example Table 1. I also need the values in the columns that are unique to Example Table 2 to align with the common columns values as they did in the Example Table 2.

If there are more records with matching values of the common columns for one table then the other, then the unique value(s) should be null as the record becomes a placeholder for the other unique values.

Table 1 has 3 records that have the values Cat 1 and Bla a in Columns A and B. Table 2 has 1 record with the values Cat 1 and Bla a in Columns A and B. So the desired table has to have two records with a null or blank value for Column E.

In my attempts to perform a Join or Full Outer Join, I get the results shown in the Example Wrong Output table.

The Desired Output Table should not contain records that repeat the values for the unique values from either table. This is shown in the Example Wrong Output Table.

Example Wrong Output:

```
Col A   | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E  
--------+-------+-------+-------+------
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-1   | D-1   | E-1     
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-2   | D-2   | E-1    
Cat 1   | Bla a | C-3   | D-3   | E-1    
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-4   | D-4   | E-2  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-4   | D-4   | E-3  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-4   | D-4   | E-4  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-5   | D-5   | E-2       
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-5   | D-5   | E-3  
Cat 2   | Bla b | C-5   | D-5   | E-4
```

Comment: You've said what you want, but what is your question? What's stopping you doing what you want to do?

Comment: My query will not fit in the comments

Comment: Please edit your answer with the query you attempted.

Comment: By having NULL in Col C and Col D (from Table 1) for one row and NULL in Col E (from Table 2) for other rows it seems to me that you are looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN. However, you sample data does not support that.

Comment: @Isaac there are no NULLs on this data running a FULL OUTER JOIN either. In fact any kind of join on Col A & B is merely going to return a lot of duplicate value combinations. The user claims there is no correlation between Cols C, D and E, but the resulting query demonstrates correlation. I see no way to resolve this without more details of the scenario.

Comment: @TimLeaf I know a FULL OUTER JOIN does not produce any NULLs with this data. All I am saying is that a FULL OUTER JOIN is the only way I see being able to produce NULLs if there were some mismatches.

Comment: @RMichalowski are you sure your sample data is representative of your situation? If it is I don't see any way to produce the desired result from the data you have provided.

Comment: @Issac, Yes this is representative of my data.

Comment: @RMichalowski If this is about a bug in your code, we'd need to see your query used to generate the 'wrong' answer. The question isn't too broad, but we are missing some of the problem query that's generating the wrong output that you're having issues with. It also helps if you can clearly state your problem in the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t1 table (
col_a varchar(5) null
,col_b varchar(5) null
,col_c varchar(5) null
,col_d varchar(5) null
)

declare @t2 table (
col_a varchar(5) null
,col_b varchar(5) null
,col_e varchar(5) null
)


insert into @t1 values 
('Cat 1','Bla a','C-1','D-1')
,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-2','D-2')
,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-3','D-3')
,('Cat 2','Bla b','C-4','D-4')
,('Cat 2','Bla b','C-5','D-5')

insert into @t2 values 
('Cat 1'   , 'Bla a' , 'E-1'   )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-2  ' )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-3'   )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-4')



select isnull(a.col_a,b.col_a) col_a, isnull(a.col_b,b.col_b) col_b, a.col_c,a.col_d,b.col_e
from (
    select *,row_number() over (partition by col_a order by col_c) rown
    from @t1
) a
full outer join (
    select *,row_number() over (partition by col_a order by col_e) rown
    from @t2
) b
    on a.col_a = b.col_a
    and a.col_b = b.col_b
    and a.rown = b.rown
order by isnull(a.col_a,b.col_a),isnull(a.rown,b.rown)
```

Using row_number as part of a full join is what allows for the null values to be created.

Comment: Is there a "Clairvoyant" badge? If so, @avery_larry deserves it for this answer. Bravo!

Comment: Wow, color me impressed. I'm not really sure why they wanted this output, but this definitely provides a correct answer based on the data provided! Good job.

Comment: I've done similar things when trying to pass data to an SSRS report in one big table for a single matrix but really should be multiple separate tables.  Full joining on row number reduces the number of null rows in the table and allows SSRS to process the data faster.

Answer (score -5):

I re did your question with a test script and expected output is in block comments let me know if this is what your looking for.

```
create table #t1 (
col_a varchar(5) null
,col_b varchar(5) null
,col_c varchar(5) null
,col_d varchar(5) null
)

create table #t2 (
col_a varchar(5) null
,col_b varchar(5) null
,col_e varchar(5) null
)


insert into #t1 values 
('Cat 1','Bla a','C-1','D-1')
,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-2','D-2')
,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-1','D-3')
,('Cat 2','Bla a','C-1','D-4')
,('Cat 2','Bla a','C-1','D-5')

insert into #t2 values 
('Cat 1'   , 'Bla a' , 'E-1'   )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-2  ' )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-3'   )
,('Cat 2'   , 'Bla b' , 'E-4')


select a.* , b.*
from #t1 a
inner join #t2 b on (a.col_a = b.col_a) and (b.col_b = a.col_b )
/* Expected output
col_a   col_b   col_c   col_d   col_a   col_b   col_e
Cat 1   Bla a   C-1 D-1 Cat 1   Bla a   E-1
Cat 1   Bla a   C-2 D-2 Cat 1   Bla a   E-1
Cat 1   Bla a   C-1 D-3 Cat 1   Bla a   E-1
*/
```

Comment: This is not even remotely what was asked for, and you didn't even insert the correct values into the tables.

Comment: enlighten me then @TimLeaf what should be the correct Table 1 if NOT TABLE 1? clearly its NOT "Desired Table" and its NOT "Wrong output"

Comment: Despite the incorrect values the query @junketsu provided is what was asked for in the question text.

Comment: The input is wrong. You didn't use the same data they provided to run the query on.

Comment: How am i taking wrong values @Isaac ?? The values are posted by op for both tables.

Comment: @Isaac the user already claimed to attempt both inner and outer joins with no success. Also there are NULLs in the desired result query, so it could not possibly be an `inner join`.

Comment: ok I guess I must be blind. Unless op has something constructive to say.

Comment: @junketsu your values for Col B and Col C of #t1 are not what the OP specified. For instance, you have 'Bla a' for all rows in #t1. The OP does not.

Comment: correct dataset: `insert into #t1 values ('Cat 1','Bla a','C-1','D-1') ,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-2','D-2') ,('Cat 1','Bla a','C-3','D-3') ,('Cat 2','Bla b','C-4','D-4') ,('Cat 2','Bla b','C-5','D-5') insert into #t2 values ('Cat 1', 'Bla a', 'E-1') ,('Cat 2', 'Bla b', 'E-2') ,('Cat 2', 'Bla b', 'E-3') ,('Cat 2', 'Bla b', 'E-4')`

Comment: But I still don't think this will help, because I cannot think of any way to produce the dataset the user requested with the data provided. I don't think we can help without more details and/or corrections on the user's part.