# Additional select if one select result is not null

Tags: sql, subquery, notnull

I am interested in the results found in table g, which shares a key, sample_name, with tables `s` and `l`. In this question the tables are 
`s` - samples, 
`p` - projects, 
`l` - analyses, and 
`g`, analysis g,
all within schema `a`. 
In the interest of optimization, I only want to look for table g after having confirmed that `l.analysis_g` is `NOT NULL`.

**Given**: The only information that I start out with is the project names. The project table, `p` is linked with other tables by the samples table `s`. `s` is linked to every table. Table `l` contains types of analysis and each column is either `NULL` or 1.

In the example below I am trying a case but I realize this may be totally incorrect.

```
SELECT s.sample_name,
       s.project_name,
       g.*
FROM a.samples s
JOIN a.analyses l
ON s.sample_name = l.sample_name
JOIN a.analysis_g g
ON s.sample_name = g.sample_name
WHERE s.project_name IN (SELECT p.project_name
                     FROM a.projects p
                     WHERE p.project_name_other
                     IN ('PROJ_1',
                     'PROJ_2'))
;
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your data and the results you want?

Comment: @daShier Table g is the only table I am interested in returning in the results. It contains the sample_id that it shares with tables `s` and `l` and the analysis results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then perhaps in the where clause?  It's still really hard to understand what you want . . .

```
SELECT s.sample_name,
       s.project_name,
       g.*
FROM a.samples s
JOIN a.analyses l
ON s.sample_name = l.sample_name
JOIN a.analysis_g g
ON s.sample_name = g.sample_name
WHERE s.project_name IN (SELECT p.project_name
                     FROM a.projects p
                     WHERE p.project_name_other
                     IN ('PROJ_1',
                     'PROJ_2'))
   and l.analysis_g IS NOT NULL
;
```

As a side note, I think you could join p.project_name and avoid the where clause.  AND I think you might want some inner joins -- but I'm not sure.

```
SELECT s.sample_name,
       s.project_name,
       g.*
FROM a.samples s
JOIN a.analyses l ON s.sample_name = l.sample_name
JOIN a.analysis_g g ON s.sample_name = g.sample_name
JOIN a.projects p ON s.project_name = p.project_name
WHERE p.project_name_other IN ('PROJ_1', 'PROJ_2')
   and l.analysis_g IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am only interested in the results from table g that contain the sample_id shared with tables `s` and `l` and the analysis results. @avery_larry

Answer (score 0):

Again: Please show an example! We can't help if we have to guess, but I'll give it a try...

If l.analysis_g contains an ID from table `g`, then you can just use:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM g
    JOIN l on g.id = l.analysis_g
    WHERE blah, blah, blah...
```

I removed your `WHERE` clause because you haven't provided enough information to allow anyone to help optimize it (if needed).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The answer from @avery_larry is very helpful. This is my first time posting a SQL question; in the interest of improving the question, could you explain what type (content and presentation) of example would be most helpful here?

Comment: @mcbridecaleb In the link, you'll see tables in text format, desired output in text format, and incorrect output in text format with explanations on why it's wrong and what is wanted.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928259/how-do-i-join-on-multiple-columns-in-sql-server-and-include-columns-in-one-table/57928924#57928924